# Why is my simple merge algorithm c++ not working?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to merge two sorted vectors into a third one. However, the compiler gives me 0 in the terminal!!

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
// merging two sorted vectors

std::vector<int> vec1{5};
std::vector<int> vec2{5};
std::vector<int> vec3{10};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 vec1[i] =  2 * i;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
 vec2[i] = 2 + 2 * i;
}

std::sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end());
std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());

std::merge(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec3.begin());

for(auto itr = vec3.begin(); itr != vec3.end(); ++itr){
    std::cout << " " << *itr; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] anf explain what makes you think that something is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you expect `std::vector<int> vec1{5};` to be size 5. You should double check that.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback! As I mentioned in the description the compiler prints 0 in the terminal when I run this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your vectors have `.size() == 1`, so you're going out of bounds, and the behavior is undefined.

Use `()` instead of `{}`:

```
std::vector<int> vec1(5);
std::vector<int> vec2(5);
std::vector<int> vec3(10);
```

You should **never** use the `{...}` syntax with containers (as opposed to `= {...}` or `{}`), because it has a rather peculiar behavior.

If the elements were not `int`s (and not constructible from ints), it would've worked as you expect:

```
std::vector<int> x(3); // size=3, [0,0,0]
std::vector<int> x{3}; // size=1, [1]
std::vector<int> x = {3}; // size=1, [1]

struct A {};
std::vector<A> x(3); // size=3, [A{}, A{}, A{}]
std::vector<A> x{3}; // size=3, [A{}, A{}, A{}]
std::vector<A> x = {3}; // compilation error
std::vector<A> x = {A{}}; // size=1, [A{}]
```

Notice that the behavior of `{...}` changes depending on the element type, but that doesn't happen with `(...)` or `= {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets you use to initialize your vectors are wrong, should be `()`, not `{}`.
See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initialize-a-vector-in-cpp-different-ways/) for 6 methods of initializing the vectors in C++.